# Linear algebra in Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $M,N$ be closed subspaces of a separable Hilbert space.

How to prove rigorously the following:

$\operatorname{dim} M >\operatorname{dim} N => \exists u\neq0 \in M, u\in N^\perp$

Intuitively it seems clear since $\operatorname{dim} M >\operatorname{dim} N$ would imply that there is a vector in $M$ which is linearly independent from a given basis of $N$. So by the decomposition $H=N \oplus N^\perp$ that vector would be in $N^\perp$. But I can't manage to write it down in a rigorous way.

I'd appreciate some direction to get started, not necessarily a complete solution.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: What have you done so far, etc.?

Comment: @dimension10: I'm trying around considering basis for M and N and looking for a suitable candidate for u as an orthogonal projection. I also looked at the contraposition. But so far I fail to see the trick.

Comment: @Tom: Then, state that in the question, in a more detailed way, else it will look like you are just demanding an answer. P.S. I didn't [downvote], yet... I may if you don't edit the question to include What You Have Done So Far...

Comment: 1. I now remove my downvote (and the other @downvoter should do the same). 2. Notice that $N$ is finite dimensional. Do you know how to prove when we are in a finite dimensional inner product space?

Comment: @Davide: no I don't. I guess the ideas I have can be applied to both finite and infinite cases...

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: There are actually three downvoters (and probably none of them has the user name "downvoter" :-)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We can assume that $M$ is finite dimensional.
2. Let $\pi\colon M\to N$ be the orthogonal projection on $N$. If the conclusion is not satisfied, then $\pi$ is injective, hence $\dim M\leqslant \dim N$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $M$ is closed in the Hilbert space $H$, you can forget $H$ and simply note that $M$ is a Hilbert space. Then for every closed subspace $N$ of $M$, we have the orthogonal decomposition
$$
M=N\oplus N^\perp
$$
obtained by the projection onto the closed convex set $N$. So if $N\subsetneq M$, it is clear that $N^\perp \neq \{0\}$. You don't need finite dimension in this approach.  Of course, in the finite-dimensional case, $N\subsetneq M\iff \dim N< \dim M$.

Finally, note that $(N^\perp)^\perp=\overline{N}$ for any subspace $N$ of $M$, as follows from the same ideas. So if $N$ is closed, $N=M \iff N^\perp=M^\perp=\{0\}$. And you get an equivalence $N\subsetneq M\iff  N^\perp\neq \{0\}$.